# Smartphone login with device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cordova, smartphone

To my understanding creating a smartphone apps based on a site is to simply create an API for the website and to output the data in XML, JSON. In my case JSON has Ruby on Rails has it built it in it. In theory all I have to is to read the event.json page and read the attribute and on phonegap to read it and build a logic from it.

However, in my phone app, I would like to allow user to log in before entering and in fact on the web-base I am using the devise gem to manage my user management. How am I supposed to allow user to log in from device using phonegap? Should I read an API JSON that showcase all users but then that may cause a lots of security issues, is there a device documentation on that specific issue, or should I scrap device and just make an authentication system from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise provides for an auth-token to be used for login. This works well with JSON APIs as you can set a header to include the auth-token to identify the user. Your login form would just be responsible for getting an auth-token from valid credentials. SSL can help to secure this information on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Gem based on [rack_iphone](https://github.com/meetme2meat/rack_iphone) which store the session

in the **localStorage** and and upon opening a application from a home screen shortcut

the application take the cookie if present from the **localStorage** and the sent it to the server

Hope this work for you